# Не могу понять как правильно работать с файлами java

Tags: java, файлы

Пересмотрел несколько лекций, несколько статей прочитал.

И так и не понял как создавать, изменять и открывать файл.

Можете расписать каждый пункт?

Comment: Текстовый файл или произвольный?

Comment: Текстовый файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Запись данных в файл:**

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("SimpleTextFile.txt", false);
fileWriter.write("Example text");
fileWriter.close();
```

Приведенный выше конструктор класса `FileWriter` имеет вид:

```
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)
```

Его параметры:

- `fileName` – путь до файла;
- `append` – флаг, если `true`, то данные *дозаписываются* в файл, если `false` – *перезаписываются*.

Если файла `SimpleTextFile.txt` не существует, то он будет создан.

**Чтение данных из файла:**

```
try {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SimpleTextFile.txt"));

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(currentLine + "\n");
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

    String text = stringBuilder.toString().trim();

} catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
    System.out.println("File not found!");
}
```

Текст, содержащийся в файле, будет находится в переменной `text`.

Если файла `SimpleTextFile.txt` не существует, то будет сгенерировано исключение `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, стал намного лучше понимать прочитав всё что вы описали. Еще раз спасибо :)